# Piping awk in R

Tags: r, unix, awk

I am trying to read in [this fixed-width file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1791181/rawk.txt) in R. I want to read in only the first 3 columns with lengths 2, 2 and 6, such that the second variable has the value "A". Note that the second variable has two spaces but is actually only one character. I am using this command:

```
b = trim(read.csv(pipe("awk -v FIELDWIDTHS='2 2 6' -v OFS=',' '($2=='A '){ $1=$1 ''; print }'</path/rawk.txt"),header=F))
```

I am getting this error:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: ($2==A
awk: cmd. line:1:       ^ unexpected newline or end of string
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  no lines available in input
```

If I remove the empty space in 'A ':

```
b = trim(read.csv(pipe("awk -v FIELDWIDTHS='2 2 6' -v OFS=',' '($2=='A'){ $1=$1 ''; print }'</path/rawk.txt"),header=F))
```

I still get this error:

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  no lines available in input
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have a look at read.fwf.

Comment: The linked file is a subset of a huge file. That's why I'm trying to parse first in awk and then read in what I need in R.

Comment: There are some examples of using gawk with `read.csv.sql` of the sqldf package in FAQ 13 and 14 on the sqldf package home page: http://code.google.com/p/sqldf

Comment: If I run that awk line outside of R I get no output, so there's something in the awk wrong.

Comment: You've got lots of single quote marks inside single quote marks... You need to escape some of them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
read.csv(pipe("awk -v FIELDWIDTHS='2 2 6' -v OFS=',' '($2==\"A \"){ $1=$1 \'\'; print }'<rawk.txt"),header=FALSE)


  V1 V2    V3
1 10 A  10001
2 10 A  10002
3 10 A  10003
```

But I'm not sure what the $1=$1 is all about...

Comment: `$1=$1` is an AWK idiom to force recalculating `$0` (whole line) from `$1`, `$2`, …, `$n` using current field separator. Any assignment to `$k` forces this operation, but sometimes you don't want to change any field. Therefore, `$1=$1`.

Comment: Many thanks, Ghoti and Spacedman. The strange thing is that that exact code worked perfectly on another file.

Answer (score 2):

For something this simple, could you not more easily look at a substring of the line rather than considering the "real" fixed-width fields within it?

```
b = trim(read.csv(pipe("awk 'substr($0,3,2)==\"A \"' /path/rawk.txt"),header=F))
```